# events.js:291 throw er; ^ Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, nodejs, headers

estoy haciendo que mi api me elimine una foto cuando elimino el producto de la base de datos el problema esta en que me lo elmina todo bien pero me salta este error:

```
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

os adjunto mi codigo
el del metodo:

```
deleteMessage: function(req, res){
        var id = req.params.id
        Oil.findById(id, (err, oil) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'error al intentar eliminar proyecto'})

            if (!oil) return res.status(404).send({message: 'no existe el proyecto solicitado a eliminar'})

            var pathToDelete ='../../uploads/' + oil.image
            fs.unlink(pathToDelete, (err) => {
                if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'error al intentar eliminar proyecto'})
                return res.status(200).send({message: 'imagen borrada'})
            })
        })
        Oil.findByIdAndRemove(id, (err, messageRemoved) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'error al intentar eliminar proyecto'})

            if (!messageRemoved) return res.status(404).send({message: 'no existe el proyecto solicitado a eliminar'})

            return res.status(200).send({
                oil: messageRemoved
            })
        })
    },
```

el del sistema de cors:

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
    //Dominio que tengan acceso (ej. 'http://example.com')
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    //Metodos de solicitud que deseas permitir
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    //Encabecedados que permites (ej. 'X-Requested-With,content-type')
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    next();
})
```

gracias por adelantado :)

---

He probado a hacer lo que me dijiste pero cuando hago la peticion la parte del unlink me devuelve este error:

```
"message": {
        "errno": -4058,
        "code": "ENOENT",
        "syscall": "unlink",
        "path": "D:\\Users\\iperez\\Cloud\\Drive\\programacion\\proyectos\\proyectos web\\uploads\\jMJvsOkGNeTHP-vHva4Kafy0.JPG"
    }
```

y tampoco me elimina la imagen sabes porque podria ser ?
gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente el problema está en esta parte del método:

```js
deleteMessage: function(req, res) {
  //...
  Oil.findById(id, //aqui hay una función callback que devuelve una llamada a res.send()
  fs.unlink(path, // aqui hay otra función callback que también llama a res.send()
  Oil.findByIdAndRemove(id, // aqui hay otra función callback que también llama a res.send()
  //...
}
```

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar operaciones asíncronas y devolver el resulta de las mismas en caso de error o de éxito.

Sin embargo, se están ejecutando las llamadas de forma paralela, por lo que se realizan 3 llamadas al método `res.send()`, lo que produce que la segunda llamada provoque el error:

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Traducido:

> *No se pueden establecer cabeceras después que han sido enviadas al cliente*

Por otro lado, estás haciendo 2 consultas a la Base de Datos, cosa que no tiene sentido si lo que harás es eliminar un documento de la misma. El método [`findByIdAndRemove()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) por sí solo basta para realizar la tarea, ya que busca un documento, y si el mismo existe lo elimina, devolviendo el documento encontrado antes de la eliminación.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Existen diversas formas de solucionar el problema, voy a mostrar 2 bastante comunes: usando [Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) y usando [Callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) anidados.

**Usando Promesas**

Las llamadas asíncronas a los métodos de Mongoose, implementan `.then()` y `.catch()` y además pueden ser usados con la sentencia `await`. Si lo hacemos con una sentencia `await`, debemos declarar el ámbito de trabajo (la función `deleteMessage`) como tipo [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona).

Por ejemplo:

```js
deleteMessage: async function(req, res) { // <= declaración tipo async
  let id = req.params.id;
  // cuando trabajamos con Promesas, debemos hacerlo dentro de bloques try/catch
  try {
    // borramos el documento
    let oilDeleted = await Oil.findByIdAndRemove(id);
    if (!oilDeleted) {
      // si no existe el proyecto, finalizo toda la operación usando return
      return res.status(404).send({message: 'no existe el proyecto solicitado a eliminar'});
    }
    // ahora intentamos eliminar el archivo
    let pathToDelete ='../../uploads/' + oilDeleted.image;
    // intentamos borrar el archivo, pero fs.unlink no implementa Promesas
    // debemos envolverlo en una Promesa para usar await
    let fileDeleted = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.unlink(pathToDelete, error => {
        if(error) return resolve(false); // si ocurre un error devuelvo false
        return resolve(true) // devuelvo true si se eliminó el archivo
      });
    });
    // ahora podemos enviar el mensaje indicando que se eliminó el proyecto
    // y además podemos enviar el valor de fileDeleted para saber si se eliminó el archivo
    return res.status(200).send({
      oilDeleted,
      fileDeleted
    });
  } catch(error) {
    // en esta parte manejamos cualquier error surgido en el bloque try
    console.error(error.message);
    return res.status(500).send({
      error: 'Ocurrió un error durante la solicitud',
      message: error.message
    });
  }
},
```

La lógica la puedes modificar más acorde a tu necesidad, pero la idea es realizar siempre una sola llamada al método `res.send()`. Como puedes observar, el mismo aparece invocado 3 veces, pero las 3 son en contextos diferentes y excluyentes, por lo tanto al llamarse una vez no será invocado las otras 2 adicionales.

**Usando callbacks anidados**

Otra forma es usar funciones callbacks de tal forma que la lógica de la aplicación se ejecute siempre dentro de las funciones `callbacks`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
deleteMessage: function(req, res){
  let id = req.params.id
  // intentamos borrar el proyecto
  Oil.findByIdAndRemove(id, (err, oilDeleted) => {
    // si ocurre un error, finaliza mi proceso con esta sentencia return
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: 'Error al intentar eliminar proyecto',
        error: error.message
      });
    }
    // si no exite el proyecto, toda mi lógica finaliza aquí con esta sentencia return
    if (!oilDeleted) return res.status(404).send({message: 'no existe el proyecto solicitado a eliminar'});

    //intentamos borrar el archivo
    let pathToDelete ='../../uploads/' + oilDeleted.image;
    fs.unlink(pathToDelete, err => {

      // todo nuestro programa continuará dentro de esta función callback
      let fileDeleted = err ? false : true;
      
      // ahora ya puedo finalizar enviando el mensaje al cliente
      return res.status(200).send({
        oilDeleted,
        fileDeleted
      });
    }); // finaliza fs.unlink
  }); // finaliza Oil.findByIdAndRemove
},
```

Esta forma también es válida para realizar la tarea y como puedes observar la cadena de eventos es escluyente (gracias a las sentencias return), lo que me garantiza que nunca se hará más de un llamado al método `res.send()`.

Como nota final, evita el uso de la palabra `var` para declarar tus variables, a menos que estés trabajando con una versión muy antigua de Node que no soporte `let` y `const`.

Comment: hola muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: pero tengo un problema porque me devuelve una path con el fs.unlink me deveulve un error que es este

Comment: El error de `unlink` es porque o bien el archivo no existe o no se tiene acceso al mismo. Te sugiero que revises que realmente la ruta es la correcta. Por otro lado, lo ideal es almacenar rutas relativas, por lo visto estás guardando una ruta absoluta. Si hubiera cambios en el sistema de archivos, las rutas absolutas se rompen en cambio las relativas se mantienen. Puedes hacer otra pregunta en el sitio indicando el problema y la forma en que guardas las rutas para ver si podemos ayudarte. Saludos @IzanPérezSánchez